# Seperate Notification icon for status bar and main notiffication

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

Well i know how build a notification , my problem is to have different icon in the status bar and background for the icon when you expand . Please see the image it is self explanatory . Thank you for helping
[image]

How to get the blue background for the small icon when expanded ? 
Thank you !!!

Comment: Try `setColor()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor%28int%29

Comment: could you please provide some code.. I really appreciate your help

Comment: nb.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary)) Use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set color Using

`.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor))`

And The complete code Looks like

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("title")
    .setContentText("content")
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary))
    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
    .setSmallIcon(small_icon)
    .setTicker(s.getText());
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(100, nb.build());
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

use this code for building notifications.

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("title")
    .setContentText("content")
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.ANYCOLOR))
    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
    .setSmallIcon(small_icon)
    .setTicker(s.getText());
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(100, nb.build());
```

in this code you have to replace small and large icons.

Comment: I am sorry but i think you understood my question ... I am asking for the background color when the notification is expanded

Comment: Try this new setColor method